The ModelState.isValid returns false IDK why in ASP.net MVC
The ModelState.isValid returns false in the POST create action
and  in the create.cshtml renders "The Customer field is required."
Customer.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}


Order.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        // Foreign key relationship to Customer
        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}


Create Action for order
        // GET: Orders/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Orders/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("OrderId,CustomerId")] Order order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(order);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name", order.CustomerId);
            return View(order);
        }

Create.cshtml for Orders
@model WebApplication1.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Order";
}

<h2>Create Order</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Order</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, "Customer", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, (SelectList)ViewData["CustomerId"], "Select a customer", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


I was expecting the ModelState.isValid to return true

Maybe you should elaborate on where you are seeing an error or describe it better instead of filling your post with spam.

From your form, I don't see you are posting the data with Customer object. It's a common error discussed in this StackOverflow community that you should use a DTO (Data Transfer Object) instead of using entity class. With DTO, you can set the fields that are needed to transfer between View to Controller and vice versa.

You may use the target framework beyond .NET 6. Beginning with .NET 6 the non-nullable property must be required, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.
To achieve your requirement, you can remove <Nullable>enable</Nullable> from your project file.
The second way, you can  add ? to your Customer property:
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    // Foreign key relationship to Customer
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
}

